# Prevent cursor changes when hovering over bootstrap button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button

I have a bootstrap link button, but it is really just for show as the reason for it is that I wanted an element that I can label with an id.

When I hover over the button though, the cursor changes to a clickable cursor and the button text content gets highlighted also.

Of course clicking on the button will not do anything. However, I do not want the cursor change and the highlight.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the style property for cursor is set to pointer on hover.

Lets say your button id was fake-button (use a "." instead of a "#" if you want it to be a class), this is the style you would need:

```
#fake-button:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: initial;
    background-color: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can only make assumptions and general suggestions without seeing any of your code.

Add a new class to the button and then add it to the CSS with declaration `cursor: default` to make the cursor default and you have to reset the background color:

HTML:

```
<button class="button button-reset-stuff"></button>
```

CSS:

```
.button-reset-stuff:hover {
    cursor: default;
    background: red; /* red being the default color of the button, which I don't know without a sample of your code */
}
```